# HttpURLConnection or HttpPost with settimeout for java 1.4

Tags: settimeout, httpurlconnection

I'm sorry if this is duplicate or repeated, need suggestion to call url by `httppost` or `HttpURLConnection` with `setReadTimeout` or `setConnectTimeout` for 15 seconds, the problem is I'm using java 1.4, `setReadTimeout()` and `setConnectTimeout()` is not available for java 1.4 package under java.net, any other alternative way, below is my code

```
URL url;                                                   
HttpURLConnection connection = null;                       
url = new URL(apiURL);                                     
connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();      
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");                       
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/json");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", ""+Integer.
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");
```

my other code

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();        
HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(apiURL);      
StringEntity input = new StringEntity(jsonBvmMEssage);     
input.setContentType("text/json");                    
postRequest.setEntity(input);                                                                                  
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's forcing you to use Java 1.4?  That's really, _really_ old!

Comment: because client still using 1.4, in future only they want to upgrade hava, but new request need to implement HttpURLConnection/HttpPost which need to have settimeout, can help me on this

Answer (score 0):

finally, I found this,

```
HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(apiURL);                    
HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();

int timeoutConnection = 15000;
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);

int timeoutSocket = 15000;
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);

DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
```

hope this will work, will test and update